# The productivity of Colab: to load directly from the Net(e.g. Kaggle) databases or to upload them on the colab directory and then extract them?

Tags: google-colaboratory, large-data, kaggle, uploading

I tried to search for the fastest approach to work with large data files in colab.  I began to wonder if it would be better to upload them directly from the site (e.g. Kaggle), or to upload them onto the colab own directory and work with them from there. I was able to do the latter, but when the files began to unzip, the system suddenly stopped working and crashed. I tried again, and next time I waited longer until everything was unzipped. However, on the second step the system crashed again.

Would you suggest the best way to work with (large) datasets without crashing the system?

The code I was using:

1)

First I made and copied a json file from Kaggle in the main directory of colab.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

! pip install kaggle
! mkdir ~/.kaggle
! cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
! chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
! kaggle competitions download forest-cover-type-prediction
```

2. 

After that, I tried to unzip the data files, downloaded from Kaggle in the directory of Colab

```
! mkdir unzipped
! unzip train.csv.zip -d unzipped
! unzip test.csv.zip -d unzipped
```

3. 

and then read the data from the csv

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("/content/unzipped/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("/content/unzipped/test.csv")

X = train.to_numpy()[100000:5000000,0:4].astype(float)
Y = train.to_numpy()[100000:5000000,4].astype(int).flatten()
```

Question: How to upload directly from the hard drive, and which method is faster?

Comment: the I tried to import it directly from the hard drive, but it did not recognize it.

Comment: Are you trying to mount your *local* drive to colab???

Comment: Of course, no. What I want to show here is these two types of loading the data in the program. The first is uploaded data inside the colab directory, and unpacking it there, the second is to upload directly from the hard drive (local) which does not happen for unknoun reasons. And, the third, which I have not shown here, because I dont know how to do is directly from the site of the data.

Comment: Actually, let me represent the question in this format: Which is the best way to import data FROM Kaggle TO Colab, and why (positives and negatives of each)? What I was looking for was the fastest and more reliable way to upload the data for use in the program.

Comment: I am afraid questions about the "best" way to do anything are actually off-topic as opinion-based; and it would seem that the answer below addresses your third way of doing it (provided of course that you will run in in colab, not in your local machine).

Comment: OK, then let me say it in other way: which would be the 'fastest' way? (if you don't like the word 'best', then best=fast). I would like the explanation of at least these 3 ways (if you think, for example that from google drive will be the best, sorry the fastest then explain, please).

Comment: About the answer of the question below: The posted answer is actually ONE of the ways I tried to do this - which was to download the files from Kaggle, then upload them in the main directory of Colab and then to unzip them at this place and use them directly in the program. However, this did not work because of lagging (I already explained in the question), is data too big or sth different idk.

Comment: I am afraid you sound confused; the answer below does **not** involve downloading anything locally: the commands shown are to be run *in colab*, and the files will be downloaded only once from Kaggle directly to colab - no uploading whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting API token from Kaggle's account tab. Then upload it in the google colab and try the following code to Initialize the Kaggle library,

```
! pip install kaggle
! mkdir ~/.kaggle
! cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
! chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

after the setup use the syntax below to download the dataset

```
! kaggle datasets download <name-of-dataset>
```

for more reference of the detailed work [click here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/how-to-load-kaggle-datasets-directly-into-google-colab/)

Comment: ok and then it starts lagging. Where does the lag come from? My PC, or the colab?

Comment: It is lagging in the cloud itself colab won't run in your computer

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov Cannot see how your PC enters the discussion here; the suggested commands are to be run in colab.

Comment: What about running the files from the PC, how can it be done? It is not explained at all here https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=yjrZQUrt6kKj

Comment: If the file is in your pc then you need to upload either in drive or in the upload file section of colab to access those.